# Cocoa - How do I initialize a view programmatically ?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, appkit

I have a problem understanding how to initialize a view without hooking it up in my nib-file. 
So what I want to do is, instead of dragging in a view and assigning it a dedicated class, I want to programmatically add it to my window in my app delegate.

I don't really know how wrong this is, but I tried something like this in my AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    DView *dV = [[DView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1000, 600)];
    [self.window addSubview:dV];
}
```

I figured that the window is an NSView as well, so why not just add it to it ? But this crashes and ends in an infinite loop. I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes,

```
MONView * view = [[MONView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
```

is correct.

---

> I figured that the window is an NSView as well

It is *not* an NSView (it is an `NSResponder`). As Richard Stahl points out, you should interact with the window's *content view* instead: `[window.contentView addSubview:view];`